# Xfce on Mint 19.3 with no Applications menu!

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, menu, xfce4-terminal

I have an old Dell Latitude D430, and I want to install a lightweight Desktop Environment.

I have installed **Mint 19.3**, with Mate, and everything seemed ok.
To make things lighter, I wanted to switch to **Xfce**, so I installed the xfce4 package from **Synaptic Package Manager**, including all the needed other packages it asked to install.

After logging out, and logging in with Xfce, I have no applications menu!
I just have the widgets for the filesystem and the web browser in the taskbar (panel), while the widget for the terminal is replaced by a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

After replicating the procedure on another machine, I realized that in Synaptic Manager I have selected and installed **only the xfce4 meta-package**, and accepted the other packages 'strictly needed' by that one.

I didn't realize that I had to explicitly **select for installation each component for Xfce**, such as the **Applications Menu**.

So, the solution is to run again the Synaptic Package Manager, and install all the other components of Xfce.